# Unable to connect Realm Browser to Realm Object Server

Tags: nginx, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using Realm Browser v. 2.1.7 and my Realm Object Server is running on an Ubuntu server behind Nginx. I can access my Realm dashboard via the browser and can connect via my mobile app.

However, when I try to connect with the Realm Browser I get the following error message:

> Failed to connect to Object Server. Check the URL and that the server is accessible.

When I check my Nginx access log I see the following:

> 204.xxx.173.126 - - [25/Apr/2017:14:15:58 -0700] "GET /realm-object-server HTTP/1.1" 404 158 "-" "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by ensuring that my Nginx was correctly configured as a Websocket Proxy. Here is my Nginx server block:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name realm.mydomain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
}
```